# Use Access Database with Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wcf, ms-access, architecture

We have some Web services (written in .NET WCF) that currently hit a Microsoft SQL Server database to retrieve/update data. We now have a requirement to also retrieve/update data from a Microsoft Access database. The Access database is currently being used by a number of legacy systems so we can't really convert it to a Microsoft SQL server database - we're stuck with an Access database.

My question is: Is there a way we can communicate with the Access database "through" Microsoft SQL Server (so that we can issue T-SQL commands to it and MS SQL Server would handle all the underlying mapping to query the Access database?) Or is it better to just communicate with the Access database via ADO.NET by exposing the location of the Access database on a network share? Does anyone have any suggestions we could try out?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about keeping the legacy access application, but moving the tables and data out of the Access application?

Access is makes a great front end to SQL server. When you build an application with Access, just like most other development tools, you have to choose what data engine and database system you going to use with Access. Access have native support built in for the JET data engine (now called ACE). Access has native support built in for SQL server.  And access 2010 not only has support built in for using SharePoint, but also SQL Auzure.

So you could consider moving the data that Access now uses to SQL server, and very little if any changes need be made to the access application.  So Access application function happy if the tables are in a file (mdb or accdb file), or server based like SQL server, and in fact for tables that reside on SharePoint, Access is in fact using web services to update that data on SharePoint. However, in all cases, the standard code, forms, VBA code and even the SQL used need not be changed.

So I don't the solution here is to attempt to attach SQL server to some "file" sitting in a folder but simply have Access attached to the SQL server to update the tables, and thsu no need to "transfer" data between the systems would exist anymore.

Comment: Hi Albert, the legacy systems are external to Access itself but connect to the Access database to retrieve data via ADO.NET. If we move the tables out of Access, wouldn't this break these existing systems (in that they won't be able to retrieve the data from Access again, but will need updating to read them from an MS SQL Server db)?

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper Access has a concept called Linked tables that are remote tables that are just like normal Access tables, except remote. Access does all the translating between Access and SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks todda, this probably seems like the way forward for us. I will experiment with both a linked server and linked tables through Access and see how things work out. Thank you both for your help on this, I have some reading to do now! :-)

Comment: Just not to sugar coat this. Compatibility is VERY high for moving of data. Little code needs changing after moving tables to SQL server. You do need an experienced Access developer to "know" what problems arise when you upsize. Most of the data or so called "upsizing" to SQL is automated, but some bits of code that will break without some tweaks. How smooth this goes can be effected if the tables etc. are poorly setup. And code changes are "minor" if one has fluency in Access code.  You can consider the other road of uploading or SQL pulling data but that is not a "live data" setup anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[Use a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx):

> A linked server allows for access to distributed, heterogeneous queries against OLE DB data sources. After a linked server is created by using sp_addlinkedserver, distributed queries can be run against this server.

If you're only ever running on a 32-bit platform:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = N'SEATTLE Mktg', 
   @provider = N'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
   @srvproduct = N'OLE DB Provider for Jet',
   @datasrc = N'C:\MSOffice\Access\Samples\Northwind.mdb';
```

Or if you have to worry about 64-bit as well:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = N'SEATTLE Mktg', 
   @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   @srvproduct = N'OLE DB Provider for ACE',
   @datasrc = N'C:\MSOffice\Access\Samples\Northwind.accdb';
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion todda. I will read into linked servers as it is new to me.

Comment: Consider this as a first step. Then you have time to migrate the Access app's backend to SQL Server.